# jQuery change background color of table row when selecting a checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have 5 columns in a table. Column 1 has a check box named name="strurl1", name="strurl2", name="strurl3" , etc.  If selected the table row background color is to change from #f1f1f1 to #e5e5e5 .

I tried but the code is not working.

The main css is

```
.overviewtable tbody tr td {
    line-height:normal;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;
    height:35px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.overviewtable tbody tr td.col1 {
    width:316px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border-left:4px solid #FFF;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#999999;
}
```

The table columns are named col1, col2, col3, col4 and col5.

Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you tried, but didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the row highlighted? Use the .closest() method to grab the row element, then add a highlighting class to it: http://jsfiddle.net/etVc8/3/

```
$(function() {
    $('td:first-child input').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have specified the background color in tbody tr td as below:  .overviewtable tbody tr td {
 line-height:normal;
 border-top:1px solid #FFF;
 border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;
 height:35px;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 background-color:#f1f1f1;
}    If I mention as $(function() {
    $('td:first-child input').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('table.overviewtable tbody tr td').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
    });
}); then only the first column containing the checkbox is highlighted.

Comment: what if i have a checkbox in <th> of a Table that Check/uncheck all checkboxes ??

Comment: @FawadGhafoorasXaineeKhan: there are a myriad of ways to handle that, for me, I prefer having the event triggered: `$('th:first-child input').change(function() { $('td:first-child input').trigger('change'); }`

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<input type="checkbox"  onclick='highlight(this)'> 1<br>
<input type="checkbox"  onclick='highlight(this)'> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox"  onclick='highlight(this)'> 3<br> 




<script>
    function highlight(obj){
       $(obj).parent().parent().css("background","#000");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have specified the background color in **tbody tr td** class as below:

```
.overviewtable tbody tr td {
  line-height:normal;
  border-top:1px solid #FFF;
  border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;
  height:35px;
  padding:10px 0 5px 0;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

If I use the following script then it highlights only the **col1** i.e the column containing the checkbox.  I will **col1** to **col5** i.e. the entire row to be highlighted:

```
$(function() {
   $('td:first-child input').change(function() {
       $(this).closest('table.overviewtable tbody tr td').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
   });
});
```